# Codeigniter - domain.de/this-is-a-test

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i "split" a releated url with a - ?

So i`ve a URL like "domain.de/thisismytest"
But i want to have "domain.de/this-is-my-test" ?

Currently i`ve this in my routes.php

```
$route['this-is-a-test'] = "site/thisisatest";
```

In my really simple Controller i`ve this Code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->home();
}

public function home() {

    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_home");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

public function thisisatest() {
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_thisisatest");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}


public function about() {
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_about");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. What do you mean by "releated url" or what do you want to split? How would you like the result look or work like?

Comment: currently my url ist domain.de/thisisatest but i want to have the url like domain.de/this-is-a-test

Comment: So the problem is that you don't want to list all the renames as in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be correct. This routing config line:

```
$route['this-is-a-test'] = "site/thisisatest";
```

remaps to the `Site` class and the `thisisatest` method.

Are you sure that you do not have this routing in config:

```
$route['thisisatest'] = "site/thisisatest";
```

? In that case both would point to the same method.

Anyways I think that the problem is that you're referencing the `thisisatest` URLs somewhere in your views. Check if your not calling `site_url('thisisatest')` or `base_url('thisisatest')` or simply `domain.de/thisisatest` somewhere in the views and replace it with `site_url('this-is-a-test')`.

Comment: you`re write in my route i`ve $route['thisisatest'] = "site/thisisatest";
But i want that the url is "this-is-a-test" and not "thisisatest".
So with a - between the words.

I forgot to rename my url in my menu view. So now it`s working thank u so much !

Answer (score 0):

In your index function you could grab the url segment and processes the string:

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment(1); // the url segment you need

$segments = explode( '-', $segment );

$yourFunction = implode ( $segments );
```

check if the function exists

```
if(method_exists($this,$yourFunction))
   $this->$yourFunction();
```

and in your routes file point to your index:

```
$route['yourController/(:any)'] = 'yourController/index';
```